# how to select monday through sunday in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have a table that keeps the last few weeks worth of data.
The system goes offline around 3am daily for a few min.
I would like to run a cron job on Monday around 3am to pull last week's data.
How would I select last week's data (Monday 00:00:00 through Sunday 23:59:59)?
I realize one way would be to simply schedule the cron for 00:00:00 on Monday but I want to run this when the system is offline so I need to use MySQL to delimit the data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is going to be your last second on Sunday - you often get into rounding errors there. One way to solve this is just to format or cast from DATETIME to DATE...

```
SELECT * 
FROM logfile
WHERE DATE(logdate) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), -1 INTERVAL day) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), -8 INTERVAL day)
```